# Why 'x' used in [ x"$VAR" = x"VALUE" ]?

Tags: shell, unix

I can see in unix shell scripts that following construction used

```
[ x"$VAR" = x"VALUE" ]
```

instead of

```
[ "$VAR" = "VALUE" ]
```

Why?

Comment: Appears to be mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes

Comment: If you're using a modern shell, quoting is sufficient. Using "x" is an archaic technique which is no longer needed.

Comment: ...and that's true for a *very* loose definition of "modern"; the `x"$foo"` idiom hasn't been useful since at least 1991, so long as one avoids the various `test` usage modes presently marked obsolescent (see the `OB` markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html; these modes are obsolescent *precisely because* they lead to ambiguities where data can be confused for syntax of `test` itself).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because shells were not always entirely well-behaved if one of the variables was empty.

Consider if `$VAR` was empty/null and `$VALUE` is "foo", your two constructs expand to:

```
[ x = xfoo ]
```

and

```
[ = foo ]
```

The latter would cause an error in some shells due to being an illegal construct, while the former is valid in any case.  This is not a problem in recent version of bash (perhaps even old versions of bash) but that's where it comes from historically - and asides from the occasional moment of puzzlement from people in your situation, there's little reason *not* to do it for compatibility with a wider range of shells.

Comment: There are quotes in my example.
I said [ "x" = x"foo" ] not [ x = xfoo ]

Comment: With quotes (and modern shells), you don't need the 'x' -- `[ "$var" = "val" ]` becomes, when var is empty: `[ "" = "val" ]` which is simply false with no errors.

Comment: @AndrejDoyle, can you identify a single shell with this bug? Even [heirloom `sh`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) doesn't have it. The bugs that *are* more readily identifiable don't relate to empty (but correctly-quoted) strings, but to strings containing only `!`, `-a`, `-o`, `(` or `)` being mistaken for `test` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

When `$VAR` is empty, it would give a syntax error `[ = "VALUE"]`, thus the usage of x to never expand to an empty value.
But since `"$VAR"` is quoted in your example, this shouldn't be a problem, becasue `[ '' = 'VALUE' ]` is a valid expression.

It also protects against a value of VAR that could be intpreted as a special flag by `[`/`test`, e.g. `VAR=-f`. Proper implementations of `test` again shouldn't be confused by this.

Comment: Yup. If you're interested in learning a lot of little things like this in advance, rather than as you stumble across them, I'd personally recommend the O'Reilly book *Classic Shell Scripting*, see http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005955 . A lot of the more obscure bits of shell scripts became a lot more comprehensible once I'd read this.

Comment: The OP's code used quotes around the expansions, making this untrue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: that depends etnirely on which shell is used. See comments on other answers on this question.

Comment: @knittl, the POSIX sh standard was published in 1991. **Every** compliant shell has the property in question. That there existed shells in the 1970s where quotes didn't make a difference is not just irrelevant today -- it was irrelevant a decade ago, and a decade before that.

Comment: @knittl, ...there *are* some undefined cases in the POSIX spec where `"x$foo"` makes a difference, but (1) they don't involve empty strings (rather, they involve cases where *a value being tested* is precisely `(`, `)`, `-a` or `-o`), and (2) they can only happen if `-a` or `-o` is in use to combine multiple operations into a single `test` invocation (syntax which has been marked obsolescent since at least the 2008 release of the standard).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old technique to prevent either side of the comparison from being empty. Some shells don't handle empty strings properly.

Comment: @Vladimir: According to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html (see the footnote), some older Bash versions don't handle empty strings correctly.

Comment: It's a shame they don't provide enough information in that footnote to permit for reproduction. The ABS does not exactly have a reputation as a source of reliable and trustworthy information; the freenode #bash channel [has been guiding folks away from it](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs) at least since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

you have got your explanations, but here's another approach, using `case/esac` instead of `if/else`

```
case "$VAR" in 
  "$VALUE" ) echo 'yes';;
  * ) echo 'no' ;;
esac
```