# how to compare strings in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting and i want to compare two strings, here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash
EXITCODE=0;
COMPARE_RESULT=sudo php /home/xxx/compareMD5.php
echo $COMPARE_RESULT
if [ "$COMPARE_RESULT"="ok" ]; then
    echo error log is not changed
    EXITCODE=10
elif [ "${COMPARE_RESULT}"="mysqlerror" ]; then
    echo mysqlerror
    EXITCODE=11
elif [ "${COMPARE_RESULT}"="apacheerror" ]; then
    echo apacheerror
    EXITCODE=12
fi
exit $EXITCODE
```

the php file will return either ok, mysqlerror or apacheerror and when i run the script, the COMPARE_RESULT prints "mysqlerror" but still goes in to if first if condition and print "error log is not changed", anyone know why? thanks

Comment: Rocket has the problem solved, but I did want to point out the inconsistency in your code.  you use $COMPARE_RESULT and later ${COMPARE_RESULT}.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: It is a good idea to compare strings using the construct `[ "x${COMPARE_RESULT}" = "xok"` to avoid trouble when `COMPARE_RESULT` is empty. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/174119/5128464).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COMPARE_RESULT=sudo php /home/xxx/compareMD5.php
```

This will not do what you think.  You need to enclose the command in backticks so that it runs and `COMPARE_RESULT` will be set to its output.

```
COMPARE_RESULT=`sudo php /home/xxx/compareMD5.php`
```

Comment: In bourne and bash '=' does work for string equality.  Otherwise, I would tend to agree with your comment as the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: In most cases, yeah '==' is a problem, and certainly that's true for a php developer, but not the issue in his code.  However, you pinpointed the issue, he's not actually storing the return value in his variable.  Because he saw output from the command line program running, he assumed it was working.

Comment: @gview: Yeah, I forgot about how bash works, haven't used shell scripts in a while :-)

Comment: Secondary issue is that without spaces around `=` in the tests they aren't actually testing what he expects.

Comment: Or enclose it like this `$(sudo php /home/xxx/compareMD5.php)`