# Difference between 'if [ "x$foo" = "x1" ]' vs 'if [ "$foo" = "1" ]' in bash?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I'm reading Gitlab's source code to learn more about how it works.  In the `run` [bash script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/blob/master/run#L32) located inside the project root directory, I see the following:

```
if [ "x$GDK_RUNIT" = "x1" ]; then
  ...
fi
```

I know this conditional's purpose is to check if the value of the `GDK_RUNIT` envar is set equal to `1`, and to exit with a non-zero return code if that's the case.  My question is, what is the difference between the above code and the following:

```
if ["$GDK_RUNIT" = "1" ]; then
  ...
fi
```

In other words, what is the purpose of placing "x" before both the envar name and "1"?

I checked `man test` for anything related to `x` (since I know `if` and `test` are functionally equivalent), but all I saw was the `-x` flag.

`x$GDK_RUNIT` doesn't look like a flag to me, so I assumed the contents of the `man` page wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely unnecessary. There are *old* implementations of `test` which cannot handle an empty argument, so if `GDK_RUNIT` is undefined or empty, it avoids the equivalent of `[ "" = "1" ]`, replacing it with `[ "x" = "x1" ]` instead. Just about any character or string would work in place of `x`, but the use of `x` was conventional.

However, no reasonably modern implementation, and certainly not `bash`'s, has this problem.

Comment: From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes), I read that a 2nd reason for this convention is that the conditional's meaning may be ambiguous if the value of the envar is set to something that resembles a flag, such as `-n`.  Is this edge case also handled by modern implementations of `test`?  If not, does this imply that a good reason still exists to use this convention?

Comment: Modern versions also use the *number* of arguments as the starting point for interpreting them. With three arguments, only the second one is considered as an operator; all the operator names start with a hyphen, but the hyphen isn't what makes them operators.

Comment: @RichieThomas, ...incidentally, what chepner just described above -- number-of-arguments being used for interpretation -- is part of why POSIX flags use of `-o` and `-a`, and other operators that lead to uses with more than three arguments excluding a possible leading `!` and trailing `]` if called under the name `[`, as obsolescent (as they reintroduce ambiguities that don't exist if they're excluded).

Comment: @chepner `...all the operator names start with a hyphen, but the hyphen isn't what makes them operators.`  So in the phrase `(test $num -gt 5)`, you mean to say it's the *position* that makes `-gt` an operator, *not* the fact that it has a leading dash character?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `operators that lead to uses with more than three arguments`... are you referring to something like `(test $num -gt 5)`, but somehow passing more than 3 arguments to `test`?  What would be an example of that?  I know you said this scenario is obsolete at this point, but you've piqued my curiosity and I'm not the type who can stop pulling a thread once I've started. :-)

Comment: @RichieThomas, `test "$num" -gt 5 -a "$num" -lt 10` is an example; as opposed to the preferred syntax of `test "$num" -gt 5 && test "$num" -lt 10`. Once you've introduced `-a` and `-o` for "and" and "or", it makes other syntax, like `'('` and `')'` for grouping, in-play, which complicates correct parsing in light of ambiguous data values substantially.

Comment: @RichieThomas : In addition to the correct response by chepner, another difference is that your second version would produce the error message _bash: [: =: unary operator expected_, due to the lacking space, while the first version is syntactically correct.

Comment: @user1934428, ...in the empty case, yes; in the non-empty case, it would be a command-not-found.